# Can't get the array with toArray in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have button for edit which is look like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.roles.edit',$role->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

The the route

```
Route::get('roles/{id}/edit',['as'=>'admin.roles.edit','uses'=>'RoleController@edit','middleware' => ['permission:role-edit']]);
```

And RoleController@edit function

```
 public function edit($id)
 {
     $role = Role::find($id);
     $permission = Permission::get();
     $rolePermissions = DB::table("permission_role")->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)
         ->pluck('permission_role.permission_id','permission_role.permission_id')->toArray();

     return view('backend.roles.edit',compact('role','permission','rolePermissions'));
 }
```

Yet, I've got the error for this `toArray()`

> FatalThrowableError in RoleController.php line 88:
>
> Call to a member function toArray() on array

I've tried `->all()`, `->get()` still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated

`Log::info` return this

```
[2017-06-20 13:23:57] local.INFO: array (
  5 => 5,
  6 => 6,
  7 => 7,
  9 => 9,
  10 => 10,
  11 => 11,
  12 => 12,
  13 => 13,
)
```

Update:
I have this in my view which should display all permissions which are assigned to this Role

```
@foreach($permission as $value)

    <label>{{ Form::checkbox('permission[]', $value->id, in_array($value->id, $rolePermissions) ? true : false, array('class' => 'name')) }}
    {{ $value->display_name }}</label>
    <br/>
@endforeach
```

`dd($permission)` return correct array also.

Comment: Eloquent returns a collection that has a `toArray()` function. You're using just the Query Builder, which automatically returns an array. There is no need for a `toArray()` function.

Comment: What version of laravel is this? In 5.3 the query builder pluck method does return a collection.

Comment: I'm using `Laravel 5.2` and if I remove `->toArray()` I've got blank empty page without any error. If I do `dd($rolePermissions` i've got `Undefined variable: rolePermission`

Comment: Why are you plucking the same column twice? Try doing `Log::info($rolePermissions)` right before you return the view, then check your laravel.log to see what's there. You can also try logging `\DB::getQueryLog()`.

Comment: Updated my question with return of `Log::info($rolePermissions)`

Comment: It looks like the query is returning your data, and `$rolePermissions` is populated. So instead you need to look at what you're using in your view.

Comment: I've updated question with the loop in my view.

Comment: Also `{{ dd($rolePermissions) }}` inside the loop is returning correct array but when I remove `{{ dd($rolePermissions) }}` or place it outside the loop -> blank white page

Comment: Can you show us what is in the `$value`? Even if the `$rolePermissions` is broken, the `{{ $value->display_name }}` should be showing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

> plunk

if you want to use toArray then use

> get

as follows:

```
 $rolePermissions = DB::table("permission_role")->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)
         ->get(array('permission_role.permission_id','permission_role.permission_id'))->toArray();
```

Comment: it returns error "Call to a member function toArray" when there is no record in database table.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, what `@aynber` said.

The clue is in the error message

> "Call to a member function toArray() on array"

You're trying to convert to an `array` when it is already an `array`.

Comment: I'm using `Laravel 5.2` and if I remove `->toArray()` I've got blank empty page without any error. If I do `dd($rolePermissions` i've got `Undefined variable: rolePermission`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `->toArray()`, as the result is already an `array` or `collection` to be more correct !